# FTP upload does not work Android

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to upload a picture from a Samsung to an FTP server using the Apache `FTPClient`. But it does not seem to work. I don't know why, the code is fine. I am trying to choose an image to upload it on the server, the `selectedImage` variable is the complete path of the picture file.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("ftpserver"));
ftpClient.login("user", "password");
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

FileInputStream buffIn = null;
buffIn = new FileInputStream(new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage)));
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
link = "http://ftpname/home/user/public_html/image/ayri.jpg";
ftpClient.storeFile(link, buffIn);
buffIn.close();
ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i've found myself the answer, for those of you who will encounter this problem, first for **POST** or **UPLOADING** files, always use Asynctask, if not it will never work. And just check that in your application you have permission for file management, you can see in settings -> Application -> Your app -> Permission -> Storage check yes. And that's it.

Thank you stackoverflow for helping !

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [`FTPClient.storeFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile(java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream)) is a **path** to file to store the uploaded data to, not an **HTTP URL**.

What that path is, depends on how your FTP server is configured.

It can be an absolute path like:

```
link = "/home/user/public_html/image/ayri.jpg";
```

Or if the `user` account is chrooted, it can be:

```
link = "/public_html/image/ayri.jpg";
```

Or something completely different. See [How to get HTTP URL of file uploaded to FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46417961/850848) (an opposite problem, but the answer will give you an idea anyway).

*(In any case, obviously the name of variable `link` is wrong, it should be `path`.)*