# Why do hyperlink in a document result in Page not found

Tags: java, hyperlink, ftp

I have written a Windows Java app (using NetBeans) that (a) uploads pdf files using FTP to my WordPress website, and (b) generates emails with embedded links to the various pdf files. E.g., the email recipients might get a email containing:

"...Here are PDF files containing the Placards. There's a separate PDF file for each Division for convenient printing on paper of different colors.:
To view Championship and Special Click on **View**"

where View is a hyperlink to the pdf previously uploaded to the website.

The app worked perfectly for several years and then I changed my hosting service to SiteGround. Now the hyperlinks bring up Page not found (404), even though FileZilla shows the uploaded files exactly where the hyperlinks indicates they should be.
SiteGround tech support told me to put the files below public_html, e.g. /concoursbuilder.us/public_html/JOCLA/MovieStars/Placards

This did not help.

I figure it must be a Java programming error because obviously FileZilla knows how to do it. Naturally, SiteGround is reluctant (unwilling?) to get into my Java programming issues. I'm at my wits end.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, thanks to answers to basically the same question, https:[//stackoverflow.com/questions/46417961](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417961)

In a nutshell, it's a matter of FTP uploading to public_html at the site so that it is at the same level as the site. See the FileZilla structure shown below. You FTP upload is uploaded to public_html. And here's the punchline: The URL for public access is the same as used for FTP upload* but with out public_html*.
[image]